# How to delete Google apps from my launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

After I have downloaded Google Chrome because my Safari wasn't finding servers, multiple google apps appeared on my launchpad that I can't delete. I uploaded a picture so you understand what I'm talking about: [http://i.imgur.com/KWy1yFV.png](https://i.imgur.com/KWy1yFV.png)

When I click on them, they open and instantly close.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

Comment: Those seem like they're shortcuts to Chrome Web Apps, but I don't know why they would appear in Launchpad.

Answer (score 2):

Type following in Chrome address bar

chrome://apps/

Now when you right click you will have the option to remove the app.

[image: chrome]